# How to create an AMI using the snapshot

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have launched an EC2 instance(us-east-1) and created a volume and attached to it. Now I took a snapshot of the volume attached and copied it to a different region(London).

Here(London) I created an AMI using the snapshot copied and trying to host an Ec2 instance using that AMI. But the instance will suddenly move to stopped status from running.

Can anyone help me to understand, why this is happening.

Comment: Are they the same instance type?

Comment: It is quite unusual for an instance to move to "Stopped" from "Running". This should only happen if a command is issued. Did the instance reach "2/2 status checks"?

Comment: Nope. It did not complete 2/2 status checks.

Answer (score 2):

To create an AMI from a snapshot using the console

1. Open the Amazon EC2 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/.
2. In the navigation pane, under Elastic Block Store, choose Snapshots.
3. Choose the snapshot and choose Actions, Create Image.
4. In the Create Image from EBS Snapshot dialog box, complete the fields to create your AMI, then choose Create. If you're re-creating a parent instance, then choose the same options as the parent instance.

   . Architecture: Choose i386 for 32-bit or x86_64 for 64-bit.

   . Root device name: Enter the appropriate name for the root volume. For more information, see Device naming on Linux instances.

   . Virtualization type: Choose whether instances launched from this AMI use paravirtual (PV) or hardware virtual machine (HVM) virtualization. For more information, see Linux AMI virtualization types.

   . (PV virtualization type only) Kernel ID and RAM disk ID: Choose the AKI and ARI from the lists. If you choose the default AKI or don't choose an AKI, you must specify an AKI every time you launch an instance using this AMI. In addition, your instance may fail the health checks if the default AKI is incompatible with the instance.

   . (Optional) Block Device Mappings: Add volumes or expand the default size of the root volume for the AMI. For more information about resizing the file system on your instance for a larger volume, see Extending a Linux file system after resizing a volume.

Comment: Where was I going wrong in the above steps I mentioned ?

Comment: Can be lot of reason for not to getting start the instance(Region not validated, EBS got corrupted). If you will share the log of instance then we can figure out the reason. Did the instance showing complete check(2/2) ?